# Enable-migrations the parameter is incorrect in website webfoms not webapp

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, webforms

While executing the enable-migration code in Package Manager Console, I am getting this error

> The parameter is incorrect. 
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG)) PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName
>   IdentityModels.ApplicationDbContext System.ArgumentException: The
>   parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG))

I have also tried the following code

```
##Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName IdentityModels.ApplicationDbContext##
```

but no luck.

P.S : Enable-Migration is working absolutely fine in Web application.